# Stop music in crafty.js

Tags: javascript, music, crafty

How do I stop a looping music file from playing in crafty.js? I want the music to stop playing once a gameover condition has been reached.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gameover scene transition](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54087/gameover-scene-transition)

Comment: I think the duplicate is the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this issue page](https://github.com/craftyjs/Crafty/issues/292): `Crafty.audio.stop("soundname");` or `Crafty.audio.stop()` to stop all sounds. Apparently [the documentation](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-audio.html) is very out of date. The issue linked is from 10 months ago, and the documentation is still out of date.

However, you can always check the [source code](https://github.com/craftyjs/Crafty/blob/master/src/sound.js#L225) to see what's available to you.

Comment: I agree that the documentation is out of date. I'll start using the source code as documentation from now on. I'll probably ask fewer questions too.