# How to fix thi gameover scene audio transition?

Tags: javascript, audio, crafty

I created a gameover scene in a crafty.js project but it does not run.

```
  Crafty.scene('gameover', function() {
    Crafty.background("#ccc");
    Crafty.audio.stop("bg");
  });

 var gameOver = function () {
    Crafty.scene('gameOver');
  };
```

The background music ("bg") doesn't stop playing once the game ends. How do I fix this?

Comment: You sure the background music is referenced with `"bg"`? If you do `Crafty.audio.stop()` does it stop?

Comment: It might be. I realised the music did not stop playing because the gameover scene was never reached. So I asked this question. @Byte56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the transition to work by removing this code:

```
  function () {
    Crafty.unbind('EnterFrame', appleEvent);
  }
```

It is the **uninit** callback for the main game scene. I wonder why it prevented the transition.

Answer (score 2):

As Byte56 said

> You sure the background music is referenced with "bg"?

And, 
Are you sure the scene is really changing?

```
Crafty.scene('gameOver');
Crafty.scene('gameover',.. );
```

you have an 'O' instead of 'o' when you call the scene, unless Crafty is case-insensitive when naming entities i don't what is the problem.

Comment: I've corrected the "o"s and checked my reference to the background music. The scene doesn't change still.

Comment: I've fixed the problem.